# Using opencv to find the shortest path for a set of 6 points on an image

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017

I have managed to find six points of interest on a 2d image. Now, i need to draw a path which is of the shortest distance to connect these points.

the path starts at point 0 and will not loop back to it.

I'm going to be drawing a line from point 0 to the next closest point, then from that point, i will draw a line to the next closest point, etc until i have reached the last point that was not connected.

the six points of interest are saved as an array of type Point2f. the index 0 of this array is the starting point.  the rest of the indices have the remaining points stored in no particular order.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Calculating distance between two points in Cartesian space is a trivial problem. With 6 points the number of possible combinations is quite small too, so there's no need to be clever. Just calculate the total distance for each combination and pick the minimum.

Comment: How would i go about doing that.. what would my loop look like? im using the cv::norm function to find the distance between points.. how do i ignore points that have already been visited? i feel a bit overwhelmed by the number of variables that i need to handle..

Comment: Convert the map into a network graph if you want to try that route https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cv::norm can be used to find distance between two points. I have taken 6 random points on a board of 200 x 200.

[image: points]

Now i have just looped over the rest of the points to find the smallest distance using cv::norm and then exchanged its index with the next point. My result is:

[image: result]

Sorry but the code is in python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def find_nn(point, neighborhood):
"""
Finds the nearest neighborhood of a vector.

Args:
    point (float array): The initial point.
    neighborhood (numpy float matrix): The points that are around the initial point.

Returns:
    float array: The point that is the nearest neighbor of the initial point.
    integer: Index of the nearest neighbor inside the neighborhood list
"""
min_dist = float('inf')
nn = neighborhood[0]
nn_idx = 0
for i in range(len(neighborhood)):
    neighbor = neighborhood[i]
    dist = cv2.norm(point, neighbor, cv2.NORM_L2)
    if dist < min_dist:
        min_dist = dist
        nn = neighbor
        nn_idx = i
nn_idx = nn_idx + j + 1
return nn, nn_idx 

#taking 6 random points on a board of 200 x 200
points = [(10, 10), (115, 42), (36, 98), (78, 154), (167, 141), (189, 4)]
board = np.ones((200, 200, 3), dtype = np.uint8) * 255
for i in range(6):
    cv2.circle(board, points[i], 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)

for j in range(5):
    nn, nn_idx = find_nn(points[j], points[j+1:])
    points[j+1], points[nn_idx] = points[nn_idx], points[j+1]

for i in range(5):
    cv2.arrowedLine(board, points[i], points[i+1], (255, 0, 0), 1, tipLength = 0.07)
cv2.imshow('image', board)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out in c++.. shouldn't be much of a hassle translating it there..

Answer (score 1):

c++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/////////////  Images  //////////////////////


void main() {

    //Blank Image 
    Mat img(512, 512, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

    float center_point_width = img.size().width / 2;
    float center_point_height = img.size().height / 2;

    Point2f center_point(center_point_width, center_point_height);

    float points_around_center[][2] = { {10.0, 10.0}, {115.0, 42.0}, {36.0, 98.0}, {78.0, 154.0}, {167.0, 141.0}, {189.0, 4.0} };
    
    int rows = sizeof points_around_center / sizeof points_around_center[0];
    int columns = sizeof points_around_center[0] / sizeof points_around_center[0][0];
    float width = 0;
    float height = 0;

    vector<float> list_of_line_lengths = {};

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < columns; column ++)
        {
            if (column == 0)
            {
                width = points_around_center[row][column];
            }
            if (column == 1)
            {
                height = points_around_center[row][column];
                Point2f target(width, height);
                Point2f difference = center_point - target;
                float line_length = sqrt(difference.x * difference.x + difference.y * difference.y);
                list_of_line_lengths.push_back(line_length);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_line_lengths.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << list_of_line_lengths[i] << endl;
    }

    bool swapp = true;
    while (swapp) {
        swapp = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < list_of_line_lengths.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (list_of_line_lengths[i] > list_of_line_lengths[i + 1]) {
                list_of_line_lengths[i] += list_of_line_lengths[i + 1];
                list_of_line_lengths[i + 1] = list_of_line_lengths[i] - list_of_line_lengths[i + 1];
                list_of_line_lengths[i] -= list_of_line_lengths[i + 1];
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "********" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_line_lengths.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << list_of_line_lengths[i] << endl;
    }

    waitKey(0);
}
```

results:

```
256.275
270.858
205.154
145.417
260.755
********
145.417
205.154
256.275
260.755
270.858
347.896
```